# How to start a program with parameters for every files in directory?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, forfiles

I'd like to run a program which takes an input file and an output file with a parameter.
I'd like to do so, for every file in my folder.

I tried with a `for` loop and `forfiles`, but I can't manage to make it work.

The syntax for the application is:

```
gdcmconv [options] file-in file-out
```

Here is my code:

```
set INPUTPATH="C:\input\"
set OUTPUTPATH="C:\Output\"

@echo on

for /D %%G in (%INPUTPATH%) do (
echo '%%~nxG'
"C:\Program Files\GDCM 2.8\bin\gdcmconv.exe" -X %%~nxG %%~nxG)
```

also tried:

```
forfiles /p %INPUTPATH% /s /m *.bat /c "cmd /c "C:\Program Files\GDCM 2.8\bin\gdcmconv.exe //X %INPUTPATH%@file %OUTPUTPATH%@file"
```

It seems it does not get the `@file` or `%%~nxG` as input or output

Comment: About `for /D` from `for /?`: If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against **directory names** instead of file names. Try `for /R "%INPUTPATH%" %%A IN (*.bat) do (echo %%~nxG & "C:\Program Files\GDCM 2.8\bin\gdcmconv.exe" -X %%~nxG %%~nxG)`. Is this working?

Comment: It seems you need to search all batch files in that folder, but you don't specify that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you request is as follows:

```
@echo off

set INPUTPATH="C:\input\"
set OUTPUTPATH="C:\Output\"

for /R "%INPUTPATH%" %%A IN (*.bat) do (
    rem echo '%%~nxG'
    "C:\Program Files\GDCM 2.8\bin\gdcmconv.exe" -X %%~nxG %%~nxG
)
```

`for /R` loops through all subfolders.

The rest of the code searches in these subfolders for `.bat` files, and process them as you requested.